# R - function like duplicated that removes all of the duplicated instances

Tags: r

Let's say we have the following:

```
c("A", "A", "B") %>% 
   cbind(1:3) %>% 
   data.frame() -> testdf
```

We want to remove from the dataframe all instances where there was a duplicate in the first variable. Usually we would use something like this:

```
testdf2 <- testdf[!duplicated(testdf$.),]
```

However, `testdf2` looks like this:

```
. V2
A  1
B  3
```

This is not what I was looking for - since the value A was duplicated, I want to remove all cases that have A in the first variable. I want my output to be like this:

```
. V2
B  3
```

Is there a function that could produce this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `testdf[!duplicated(testdf$.)&!duplicated(testdf$.,fromLast = TRUE),]`

Answer (score 3):

Another `base`alternative(retains row names):

```
testdf[-which(testdf$`.` %in% testdf[duplicated(testdf$.),1]),]
  . V2
3 B  3
```

Answer (score 2):

If want to stick with pipes

```
 testdf %>% group_by(testdf$.) %>% summarise(num_x=n()) %>% filter(num_x==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` with `table`

```
subset(testdf, `.` %in% names(which(table(`.`) == 1)))
# . V2
#3 B  3
```